# Spring - Best way to set multiples urls - setDefaultTarget

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application where I have the `setDefaultTargetUrl('...')` in the `SuccessfulLoginHandler`.

Now I have to implement one case where the user could login an see a different view. So far what I have done is:

```
@Service
public class SuccessfulLoginHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler{

    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public SuccessfulLoginHandler(UserService userService){
        this.userService = userService;
        setDefaultTargetUrl("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = AccessService.getUser(authentication);
        if(this.userService.isFirstLogin(user)){
            setDefaultTargetUrl("/firstlogin");
        }else{
            setDefaultTargetUrl("/app");
        }
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way. It is working properly but could be a problem in case 2 users login simultaneously.

What would be the right way to implement the "redirect".

Comment: solution looks good to me. also - there shouldn't be a problem if 2 users login simultaneously (the only shared resource is the userservice, and should be threadsafe)

Comment: I think you are right, but I have moved the logic to my controller just to be sure and there I do the redirect.

Answer (score -1):

After successful login, you can try to redirect users to a default url.

If you are using Spring Security, you can simply set a success url or failure url.

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .failureUrl("/login?login_error=t")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/app")
        .permitAll()
```

If you want to set some custom logic after a successful login, you can do something like this,

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    if(queryString == null) {
        response.setStatus(200);
    } else if(!queryString.contains("redirectUrl=")) {
        response.sendRedirect("/");
    } else {
        queryString = URLDecoder.decode(queryString.replace("url=", ""), "utf-8");            
        response.sendRedirect(queryString);            
    }
}
```

**P.s.** For redirection, if you prefer server side redirection, you can use request.getRequestDispathcer instead of response.sendRedirect.

**EDIT**: concurrent login should not cause any problems, since the userService a read only service and should not raise race condition issues.